# upload picture in window form using c#

Tags: c#-2.0

the images should be store in a directory(image) under the project

Comment: can you clarify your question?

Comment: Or at least post the part of code you are having problems with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows forms, the user doesn't need to 'upload' the file, because the application runs locally. Instead, ask the user for a filename (typically through an open dialog); then copy the indicated file to the target location.